# Intermittent Y-shift print issue only with multiple items

Tags: creality-ender-3, pla

I have an issue with a Y-shift every few lines **only** when printing multiple items at once. If I print the *exact same models* individually, they each print fine. Notice the shift only happens a few times, about every 4 lines, and then stops happening.

I’m printing PLA on an Ender 3 Pro, slicing with Cura 4.8 (Mac).

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

[image: Annotated image of both multiple and single prints]
[image: Failed print on bed]
[image: Two towers showing Y-shift]
[image: Closeup of failed print showing layering]

Comment: have you tried printing the part rotated by 90° around Z? I suspect it is a mechanical thing, the nozzle getting *snatched* by the print in a hole as it moves....

Comment: I suspected a mechanical problem as well, perhaps a loose grub screw on a shaft.

Comment: I will check these items; thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I initially tightened the tensioner for the x-axis belt pulley, which seemed to help. Then I double-checked my installation, and realized the belt for the x-axis was on upside down (belt teeth go in, smooth side of belt out).

So I guess it’s actually more surprising it’s been working well until now...

Comment: I guess that means it was also an X-axis layer shift, not a Y-axis one.

Comment: Yes, sorry, 3D-printing newb (obviously). "Never believe what the user tells you", right? ;)